# Different response from bot emulator and chatbot in web

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have created a chatbot in web channel and direct line.

When i tested in bot emulator i get the right response and when i try to test the same intent in localhost ( webchat) i got different response.

I will show you and example :

- call an agent
- give me your customer number
- ( after custemer number was sended ) are you sure ?
- if you click Yes ...the data are stored in database ( sql server )

If you do the save in localhost you get : You cancelled the form ( in fact i havent cancell any form

Here is the luisdialog here i call the form :

```
        [LuisIntent("human")]
    public async Task human(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {

        var form = new FormDialog<Human>(
         new Human(),
         Human.BuildForm,
         FormOptions.PromptInStart,
         result.Entities);
        context.Call<Human>(form, LossFormCompleted)

    }


    private async Task LossFormCompleted(IDialogContext context, 
        IAwaitable<Human> result)
    {
        HumanCall form = null;
        try
        {
            form = await result;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        if (form == null)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("You cancelled the form.");
        }
        else
        {
            //call the LossForm service to complete the form fill
            var message = $"Your data are stored in database";
            await context.PostAsync(message);
        }
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

The form model is :

```
[Serializable]
public class Human
{


    [Prompt("What is your contract number?")]
    public string contract;





    public static IForm<Human> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<HumanCall> wrapUpRequest = async (context, state) =>
        {

            using (BotModelDataContext BotDb = new BotModelDataContext())
            {
                tblBot bot = new tblBot();
                bot = BotDb.tblBots.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Reference == state.contract);


                if (bot != null)
                {
                    using (bbbserviceSoapClient cws = new bbbserviceSoapClient())
                    {
                        viewc a= new viewc();

         a.Lastname = bot.Lastname;


                    }
                }
            }




        };
        return new FormBuilder<Human>().Message
        ("can you send us some info ?")

        .Field(nameof(contract))

            .OnCompletion(wrapUpRequest)
            .Confirm("Are you sure: Yes or No. ")
            .Build();
    }


 }
 }
```

Can someone help me where i'm wrong ? What can i do to retrieve the same response ? It's about timeout problem or what do you thing ?

Answer (score 1):

I do a test based on the code that you provided and make slight modifications, and I find that if some exceptions occur in `wrapUpRequest` method, it would show ***"You cancelled the form"*** instead of the message ***"Your data are stored in database"***.

[image]

So I suspect that exceptions occurring in `wrapUpRequest` method *(perhaps database query issue or request sent by bbbserviceSoapClient is timeout etc)* when you do test via web chat, which causes the issue.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to implement/write custom log to detect if any exception occurs within `wrapUpRequest` method when you test via web chat.